# Filter line chart in Power BI with legends

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics, powerbi-embedded

I've an Azure Stream Analytics job that is constantly sending data to Power BI to show real time data.

This is a sample of my dataset:

```
[
   {
      "speed" :98.6,
      "timestamp" :"2018-09-19T19:34:50.315Z",
      "tag" :"AAAAA555555"
   }
]
```

I'm using timestamp for Axis, tag for Legend and speed for values.

I created a simple line chart in my dashboard which is
***speed BY TIMESTAMP AND TAG***

Suppose I have 100s of tags then the line chart would become indistinguishable.  Is there a way I can add a drop down or some kind of filter which will list all the tags and I can pick and choose which ones to show on the chart?

Comment: Have you tried adding a slicer for the `tag` field? That should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the slicer visualization and add the "tag" column to filter the tags in the line chart:

Can check in the page [Slicers in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-slicers) how to do it.

Hope can help you!